# Common security group for vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I have an AWS VPC. I am trying to structure my security groups in a manner so that I can allow traffic between specific ports between all my instance. So far, I have this:

```
   VPC security group - >
     ingress:  allow traffic to self from all ports ( self sg-id)
     egress:   allow traffic from vpc to vpc cidr 

   Consul-instance group ->
     ingress: allow traffic to self from consul ports ( self sg-id)
     ingress: allow all traffic from vpc sg-id
     egress:  all traffic to vpc cidr

   App-instances group ->
     ingress: allow traffic to self from app-instances ( self sg-id)
     ingress: allow all traffic from vpc sg-id
     egress:  all traffic to vpc cidr
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but this does not seem to work in a way that consul instances can communicate with each other, app instances can communicate with each other but app-instances and consul cannot communicate with each other.

Is it really required to specify vpc cidr as ingress source for all my security groups? I tried this as well but does not seem to work. Not sure what am I missing.

EDIT-1:

Example: I cannot telnet from one of my app-instances to consul instance on port 8085

```
     telnet {consul-host} 8085
     Trying x.x.x.x........
```

If i explicitly open ports between these two groups on port 8085 from vpc cidr then I am able to reach the host:port. But the idea of using one security group common across VPC for routing traffic does not work! I am using terraform to achieve this.

EDIT-2

This is considering a standard setup of a vpc with public and private subnets where internal traffic is routed via route-tables between the vpc

Comment: Please clarify your expectation and what doesn't work (e.g. via ping)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: The question still too vague.  SG is just a virtual firewall rules for individual EC2 instance/etc services. By default, all instance in the same subnet can communicate with each other with default SG. Your question didn't provide any details about each instance subnet CIDR.  So it can be due to subnet communication issue than SG.  VPC still follow the IP routing rules, if you put one instance in 172.16.1.0/24  subnet and another inside 172.16.2.0/24 subnet,  they can't talk to each other without proper routing configuration.